# I do not understand the terminology of $Q_n$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, terminology, descriptive-statistics, order-statistics

I am trying to understand what looks to be some simple terminology issue, involving $Q_n$ from my book here:

[image]

Specifically, I do not understand what they mean when they say $m = {n \choose 2}$, and what they mean when they say $k = {[n/2] + 1 \choose 2}$.

As far as I know, this terminology means "something choose something", (in relation to combinations, etc), but I do not see how it possibly applies in this case. Am I misinterpreting this terminology, or does it mean something all together, and if so, what does it mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be "chose"? I am pretty sure that is what it is.

Comment: [See wiki article on "n choose k" notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: There appears to be a typographical error: "$z_{(k)}$" must mean the difference $d_{(k)}$.  By definition of the binomial coefficients, there are $m = \binom{n}{2}$ such differences.

Comment: @PeterFlom I think I know what was confusing me. Coming from a time-series analysis I had assumed the data set would be ordered in time, and so the 'difference' would just be one sample minus the one before it. It appears as though he means ALL possible differences, of which there are ${n \choose 2}$.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for pointing that out, I was wondering what the 'z' was here as well. I think it all makes sense now, esp your comment on the number of differences. (See my comment to @PeterFlom). Thanks again.

Comment: @whuber I do not understand the $i > j$ part here though. What are they indicies of? Why does $i > j$ here? Are they just indicies of my original data $x$? Confused...

Comment: Standard order statistic notation: suffixes such as $(i)$ denote the $i$th smallest value.

Comment: @NickCox Ah! So $d(k)$ is the difference of the ORDERED set $x$, where 'difference' here means not one ordered value minus its predecessor, but all the possible combinations of differences, such that $i > j$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am explaining just one detail. You don't even give a reference here ("my book"???), so it's hard to check the entire thing in context. COuld be Maronna et al. Robust statistics, but my copy is not to hand.